# static Object Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, static

i wannt to create a static Object inside a methode. The Class of the methode has an Pointer oft which has the type Player. Phayer is an Abstract Class. Now i want to let the pointer point at an Object which inherits from Player. That Reference shouldn't be lost when the Methode is closed.
The poiner is initializied like this:

```
pragma once
include "Player.h"
include "Matchfield.h"

class Game
{

public:
    Game();
    ~Game();
    void start();
private:
    Player *playerone;
    Player *playertwo;
    Matchfield gamefield;
};
```

In the moment im am doing it like this:

```
    Game::Game()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        switch (CLI::getplayer())
        {
        case 0:
        {
            static HumanPlayer x;
            playerone = &x;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            BotOne x;
            playerone = &x;
        }

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Another method then tries to call a method from the object that the pointer refernces.

```
int actMove;
    int inheight;
    while (true) {
        actMove = playerone->play(gamefield);
        inheight = gamefield.columnHeight(actMove);
... Bla Bla just boring stuff
```

I get the mistake that it is not possible to find my Object, why? Isn't static?

Thank you for your answer, i appreciate it!:)

Add minimalistic Example for the Problem:

```
class Player
{
public:
    Player() = default;
    ~Player() = default;
    virtual int play(Matchfield ActField) = 0;
    bool ishuman;
};

Game::Game()
{

    static HumanPlayer x;
    playerone = &x;

}
```

HumanPlayer is not an abstract class;
Now i want to use the pointer Playerone somewhere else.
For example here;
play in Humanplayer would return an int;

```
int Game::play(){
return = playerone->play();
}
```

Comment: 1) Please provide [mcve]. 2) "_Isn't static?_" `BotOne x;` isn't static, and you are left with a dangling pointer in `playerone`, when it leaves the scope (of `case 1`), and any usage of it invokes undefined behavior. 3) `playertwo` isn't even initialized, hence any usage of it invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Why should there be a angling pointer for playerone. HumanPlayer ist static. I get the Problem here: actMove = playerone->play(gamefield);

Comment: That's why I asked for [mcve]. I have no idea what your `CLI::getplayer()` returns. If it returns `1`, the `playerone` is left with a dangling pointer, since `BotOne x;` isn't static.

Comment: Anyway the HumanPlayer and BotOne objects you create in your for loop do not exist outside of your for loop's context so you have a conception error to start with.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois `HumanPlayer` object **does**, still, exist after the `switch` case has finished executed (and, in turn, the loop), due to the fact that it is `static`. `BotOne` isn't static, and due to that fact, yes, it does get destroyed after its scope ends.

Comment: I added an Example i hope it is good!

Comment: @Chipato That is still, not an [mcve]. Did you read the link, that I provided you multiple times?

Comment: What is missing?

Comment: `What is missing?` You are missing  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question about `static` pointers in classes:
Header file:

```
class Game
{
public:
    Game();
    ~Game();
    void start();
private:
    static Player *playerone;
    static Player *playertwo;
    Matchfield gamefield;
};
```

Source file:

```
Player * Game::playerone = nullptr;
Player * Game::playertwo = nullptr;

Game::Game()
{ ; }

Game::~Game()
{
  delete playerone;
  delete playertwo;
}

void Game::start()
{
  delete playerone;
  delete playertwo;
  // Example:
  playerone = new Human;
  playertwo = new Bot;
}
```

Since the pointers are variables, they follow the same syntax a static variable inside a class.

The `static` keyword means that there is one instance for all `Game` instances, and *instances of their derived classes*.  They all *share* the same `playerone` and `playertwo`.

**Edit 1:  Static in a method**
A `static` variable in a method is only accessible within the method.  The `static` keyword says that the variable will exist after execution leaves the function.  So, next time the function is entered, the variable will have the same value from the last execution of the function.

```
void AddOne()
{
    static int value = 0;
    std::cout << "Previous value: " << value << "\n";
    ++value;
    std::cout << "Value after add: " << value << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
  AddOne();
  AddOne();
  AddOne();
  AddOne();
  return 0;
}
```

The above code demonstrates the lifetime of the `static` variable.

Comment: Hey Thank you for your Answer. It hepled me! I have the problem that i have different Bots. The User will choose a bot. I want to implement that a Player can decide which bot to use. So i want to make it possible that a Method lets the Point refernce to different Objects that inherit from Player, depending on what bot to use. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, either prompt the User in the `start` method or pass them as parameters to the `start` method.  See `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score -2):

You can declare the pointer to be static, so it will not lose the reference when it exits the method, but whenever you instantiate an object of type `Game` the pointers will already be filled with that value. You can do:

```
class Game
{

public:
    Game();
    ~Game();
    void start();
private:
    static Player *playerone;
    static Player *playertwo;
    Matchfield gamefield;
};
```

Comment: How can i not lose the reference exiting the methode? For Playerone?

Comment: You can do:

class Game
{

public:
    Game();
    ~Game();
    void start();
private:
    static Player *playerone;
    static Player *playertwo;
    Matchfield gamefield;
};